# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "xx" does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I was trying to add a new column to a database table by using `make migrations` on Django, bit didn't work and I got some weird errors. Following advice on another SO post I used `DROP TABLE` to delete the table and start again.

The problem is, now when I try to migrate the table it doesn't appear in my PostgreSQL database. When I check `make migrations` I don't get any changes to migrate suggesting it is synced. I have also run: `python3 manage.py migrate --run-syncdb` and still getting no luck.

I'd appreciate any help.

```
class UserVenue(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(mapCafes, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    user_list = models.ForeignKey(UserList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['user_list','venue']
```

For some reason I can still see the table in Django Admin but then get this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/testingland/uservenue/

Django Version: 3.1.7
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.gis',
 'testingland',
 'rest_framework',
 'bootstrap_modal_forms']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (relation "testingland_uservenue" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "testingland_uservenue"
                                          ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 614, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 233, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1693, in changelist_view
    cl = self.get_changelist_instance(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 735, in get_changelist_instance
    return ChangeList(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.get_results(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py", line 235, in get_results
    result_count = paginator.count
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 94, in count
    return c()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 411, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 515, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 500, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/testingland/uservenue/
Exception Value: relation "testingland_uservenue" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "testingland_uservenue"
                                          ^
```

Comment: You dropped the table in the DB, but your migrations still think the table is there, so your migrations need to also reflect this. You can reset your migrations to zero and run it all again.

Comment: I see, how do I reset my migrations to zero?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#reversing-migrations

Comment: Unfortunately it is still creating the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the following or do all:

Delete all files in the migrations folder

Delete/Drop Table django_migrations

Delete/Drop Table error

Then rerun your migrations & migrate

(this way worked for me)